# AutoMapper Configuration Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, automapper

I have a model class

```
public class Brochure
    {
        [Key]
        public int BrochureId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfCover { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }
        public LibraryType Type { get; set; }
    }
```

and View model

```
public class BrochureView
    {
        public int BrochureId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfCover { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }
    }
```

in Brochure service I'm mapping model and viewmodel

```
public class BrochureService
    {
        private BrochureRepository _brochureRepository;

        public BrochureService(DbContextOptions<LibraryContext> options)
        {
            _brochureRepository = new BrochureRepository(options);
        }

        public void Create(BrochureView brochureView)
        {
            var brochure = Mapper.Map<BrochureView, Brochure>(brochureView);
            brochure.Type = LibraryType.Brochures;

            _brochureRepository.Create(brochure);
        }
    }
```

Here is my automapper profiler:

```
public static class AutoMapperProfile
    {
        public static void RegisterMappings()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Brochure, BrochureView>();

                cfg.CreateMap<BrochureView, Brochure>()
                .ForMember(src => src.Type, opt => opt.Ignore());

            });
        }
    }
```

but i have an exception:
[image]

Unmapped members were found. 
AutoMapper cant map "Type" property. How can I resolve this problem?

To answer question from comments, that's the whole MappingProfile

```
public static class AutoMapperProfile
    {
        public static void RegisterMappings()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Book, BookView>();
                cfg.CreateMap<BookView, Book>();

                cfg.CreateMap<Magazine, MagazineView>();
                cfg.CreateMap<MagazineView, Magazine>();

                cfg.CreateMap<Brochure, BrochureView>();
                cfg.CreateMap<BrochureView, Brochure>()
                    .ForMember(src => src.Type, opt => opt.Ignore());


                cfg.CreateMap<PublicHouse, PublicHouseView>();
                cfg.CreateMap<PublicHouseView, PublicHouse>();

                cfg.CreateMap<Book, LibraryView>()
               .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.Name))
               .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => (LibraryType)src.Type));

                cfg.CreateMap<Brochure, LibraryView>()
              .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.Name))
              .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => (LibraryType)src.Type));

                cfg.CreateMap<Magazine, LibraryView>()
              .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.Name))
              .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => (LibraryType)src.Type));
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include that code that registers AutoMapper and invokes `RegisterMappings`. Have you added a breakpoint to the `ForMember` line to confirm it's being executed?

Comment: Sorry - I don't think my question was clear. I'm looking for where in your code you actually *call* `RegisterMappings`.